# How to get Selenium to print browser logs while running in Docker?

Tags: c#, docker, selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriver

I am trying to debug an issue with one of my Selenium test cases, written in C#, and I want to see the browser logs I've put in the frontend. I need these logs to show when I run the test in Docker, because when I run it locally through my IDE it passes, but when it runs on Docker it's failing.

This is the code I have to try and get the browser logs.

```
    var entries = Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
    foreach (var entry in entries) {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
    }
```

Which shows the logs fine when I run the test locally, through my IDE, but when I run in Docker this line of log doesn't show anything. (But other Selenium logs using `Console.WriteLine()` do show up on Docker.) Is there a way to get the logs showing when I run my tests in Docker?